# Django: custom ManyToMany field in form

Tags: django, forms, widget, many-to-many

I want to display a ManyToMany field into a widget/Html-form which the user can delete by X-ing items using jquery.

```
class user_profile:
  links = ManyToManyField(...)
```

Then when I render the formset it would be something like:

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="link_to_delete_item_using_ajax_call" />
  ....
  ....
</form>
```

Is there any existing? If not, how should I code it? ModelForm? Custom Form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best place for this is usually a custom Widget class. For example you could subclass [CheckboxSelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple) and then use your custom widget in your form classes for relevant form fields.

The widget can automatically include the required JS/CSS by specifying it in the internal [Media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/media/#combining-media-objects) class